# What's wrong with this metalsmith-in-place build script?

Tags: nunjucks, metalsmith

I am trying to use metalsmith-in-place to do some in-place templating on files in subdirectories of my source dir. It doesn't work. Template tags are not replaced by the frontmatter.

My build script:

```
var Metalsmith = require('metalsmith'),
  inplace = require('metalsmith-in-place'),
  nunjucks = require('nunjucks');

Metalsmith(__dirname)
  .source('./source')
  .use(inplace({
    engine: 'nunjucks',
    pattern: '*.html',
    directory: 'source/deeper'
  }))
  .destination('./build')
  .build(function(err) {
    if (err) {
      console.log(err);
    }
    else {
      console.info('Built it.');
    }
  });
```

My template:

```
metalsmith_debug$ cat source/deeper/index.html
---
title: My pets
---

{{title}}
```

My output:

```
metalsmith_debug$ cat build/deeper/index.html

{{title}}
```

It works on files in `source`; but I need it to work on subdirectories.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A couple of changes:
`build.js`:

```
var Metalsmith = require('metalsmith');
var inplace = require('metalsmith-in-place');
// var nunjucks = require('nunjucks');

Metalsmith(__dirname)
.source('./source')
.use(inplace({
    engine: 'nunjucks',
    pattern: '**/*.html' // modified pattern
    // directory: 'source/deeper' // Not needed
}))
.destination('./build')
.build(function(err) {
    if (err) {
        console.log(err);
    }
    else {
        console.info('Built it.');
    }
});
```

1. You don't need to require nunjucks within the build file, `metalsmith-in-place` uses `consolidate`, this will require it where necessary. (Line can be removed)
2. Modify `pattern` within `inplace` to `**/*.html`. For more information see [Globbing patterns](https://www.npmjs.com/package/multimatch#globbing-patterns).
3. `directory` isn't needed within `inplace`. (Line can be removed)

... and a minor change to `source/deeper/index.html`:

```
---
title: My pets
---

{{ title }}
```

4. Added space around the placeholder `{{ title }}` - [Nunjucks](http://mozilla.github.io/nunjucks/templating.html#variables) seems to think this is important.

Should work now for you, let me know if not.

Answer (score 3):

The accepted answer is outdated now, because `metalsmith-in-place` switched to use the [jstransformer](https://github.com/jstransformers/jstransformer) framework instead of `consolidate`.

I've written an article on how to use the `in-place` plugin to pair Nunjucks with Metalsmith:

- [Making Metalsmith to work with Nunjucks](https://medium.com/@slavafomin/making-metalsmith-to-work-with-nunjucks-a67a74c3e73d)

Here's the minified working example:

```js
const Metalsmith = require('metalsmith');
const inPlace = require('metalsmith-in-place');

Metalsmith(__dirname)
  .source('./src')
  .destination('./build')
  .use(inPlace({
    pattern: '**/*.njk',
    engineOptions: {
      path: __dirname + '/src'
    }
  }))
  .build(function (error) {
    if (error) {
      throw error;
    }
  })
;
```

Answer (score 1):

Your `pattern` in the `inplace` configuration should most likely be `**/*.html` rather than just `*.html`

Comment: I thought that might work, but in fact it causes a template error on build. As things stand, *.html gets the entire directory tree (so if I set the directory as source, I get the stuff in source/deeper). But the stuff in subdirectories is not processed. So it doesn't seem like an issue with the path?

Comment: Just following up on my prior comment: The template error I was seeing was due to some invalid HTML in source tree. +1 for this answer, which was partial but correct.